# Object initializers in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, object-initializers, object-initializer

In C# I can do this:

```
foo( new SomeClass() { SomeProperty = "value" } );
```

Now in C++/CLI I can equivalently do this:

```
auto tmp = gcnew SomeClass();
tmp->SomeProperty="value";
foo (tmp);
```

But is there a syntax for C++/CLI that is similar to C# object initializers?  In particular I don't want to define a temporary variable and I can't add arguments to the constructor itself.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such initialization possible in C++/CLI. New constructor would be the way to go - why can't you have it?

Comment: Well, it's not totally out of the question. But there are a decent number of properties that are all optional. So it would mean many different constructors to handle all the different combinations. C# object initializers handle this beautifully so I was just hoping for a c++/cli analog. Otherwise I think the temporary variable will probably be the less painful route for my case.

Comment: I see. Well, another option may be to have a constructor taking all possible properties in by reference, passing `nullptr` in place of uninitialized properties. I think your approach is more readable though.